# Is there a known English translation or Commentary on the Agastya Shakti Sutras

Tags: vedanta, translation-request, shaktism

I have found a set of Shakti Sutras written by Agastya [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/shaktisuutra.html?lang=sa).

What is present there are the Sanskrit verses. Many other websites mention that it is related to Srividhya Upasana and a profound Shakta view.

Does anyone have an English translation or commentary for it (even in Sanskrit is fine)?

Comment: Found one [Russian translation](https://wiki.shayvam.org/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B) can be [translated into English](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.shayvam.org%2F%25D0%25A8%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8-%25D1%2581%25D1%2583%25D1%2582%25D1%2580%25D1%258B&edit-text=&act=url).

Comment: @Pandya: Amazing, Thanks. While that helps get prima facie understanding of the sutras, a commentary will help us get deeper understanding. Thanks for this.